# Filter month QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

How do I filter the month `QSqlTableModel`?

I'm doing this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("sqlite.db");
db.open();

model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable("table"); // db sqlite
model->setFilter("strftime('%m', date_field)='04'");//db YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
model->select();
```

But without success.

Comment: You should also define your database: model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);

Comment: @Nejat added the db, but yet does not filter results by month.

Comment: Do you have a column name "date_field"? Do you specify the column name correctly?

Comment: @Nejat Yes, `DATETIME` format. Stored in this format `2014/04/24 10:10:10`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, The problem was the date format stored in `SQLite`. Converts the date to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and ran the filter.